# Unable to close print file handle in perl

Tags: perl, printing

I have the following perl snippet:

```
open FH, " | lpr ";
print FH "Hello";
print FH "This is a print test";
close FH or die "can't close: $! $?";
```

I am getting the following output:

```
can't close: 256 at <filename> line 4
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6):

From [perldoc -f close](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html)

> If the file handle came from a piped open, "close" will
>                  additionally return false if one of the other system
>   calls
>                  involved fails, or if the program exits with non-zero
>   status.

The missing error is probably due to your lpr-process is not done, or something went wrong there. Did the print work?

Comment: the print is not working... I think the printer will start printing only after the file handle gets closed.

Comment: You should probably check that the `open` is successful too. `use autodie` can be handy, as that will do all the checking for you on vital functions. You might find a useful module at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org)

Answer (score 1):

If the filehandle came from a piped open, close returns false if one of the other syscalls involved fails or if its program exits with non-zero status. If the only problem was that the program exited non-zero, `$!` will be set to 0 . Closing a pipe also waits for the process executing on the pipe to exit--in case you wish to look at the output of the pipe afterwards--and implicitly puts the exit status value of that command into `$?` and `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}`.